# Apache ProxyPassReverse not rewriting Location header properly

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, mod-ssl

I'm configuring apache to proxy SSL requests to a local backend server. Here are the relevant parts of the virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

  ...

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/server.key

  RewriteEngine On

  <Proxy balancer://unicornservers>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8080
  </Proxy>

  # Redirect all non-static requests to unicorn
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://unicornservers%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://unicornservers/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  ...

</VirtualHost>
```

When I use curl to access the server (`curl -vk https://example.com`), the backend server performs a redirect to `/login`, as it is supposed to.

The problem is, apache is not rewriting the `Location` header properly. It returns a location of `http://example.com/login` instead of `https://example.com/login`.

Is there somewhere in my config where I need to tell apache to use `https` for the `ProxyPassReverse` rewrite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I had improperly diagnosed this. The backend webserver (in this case, it happened to be rails) was actually specifying the `http` URL explicitly. This is because it was using the incoming request parameters to build its redirection URL. So, since `ProxyPreserveHost` was enabled, it was getting the host right, but not the protocol.

To fix it, I added the following line to my apache config:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

This way, the backend rails server knows that the original request was over SSL, and it generates the redirection URL properly.